# Find points of angles in a rectangle in 3D coordinate system

Tags: c++, 3d, openni, point-cloud-library

I have points in 3D which make 2 or 3 side of rectangle. How I can calculate the coordinates of the cube's corners? Is it possible?

[image: pcl]
[image: pcl]
[image: pcl]
[image: pcl]

Updated: https://github.com/CPIGroup/3d-Camera-scanDimensions

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? I don't understand what you mean by "points of the angles". Do you mean the vertices?

Comment: what do you mean with points of angles? Angles between points, point normals?

Comment: If I understand correctly, he's got a set of points all lying on 2 or 3 sides of a cube. He needs to calculate the coordinates of the cube's corners (in Russian "angle" and "corner" are the same word).

Comment: Magtheridon96 and user2116939, yes you are right, I need find corners to build rectangle and find dimensions :)

Comment: user2116939 thank you :)

Comment: @user2116939 Interesting! "Angle" and "Corner" are the same? Oof, that must make talking about 3d modelling a pain...

Comment: @JerKimball, well ... when talking about "angle" one just always says "angle between". That is - angle between 2 lines or 2 planes or whatever. When it is corner, it is just corner. Simple enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea, not a proven method.

First, find the planes. Randomly select 3 points, find a plane that passes through them, normalize the 4 parameters. Repeat 1000 or so times. You will end up with 1000 4-tuples of numbers. Use one of the [clustering analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Density-based_clustering) methods to find 2 or 3 groups of 4-tuples that are very close together. Average each of the groups. These will be, approximately, planes of your box's sides.

Now make them more precise. For each plane, find all points that are close to it but not close to other planes (for some value of "close", perhaps to be found using a clustering method too). For each such group of points, find a best fit plane using [least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares).

If you have three planes, great; intersect them and you have a vertex and three edges. For two planes, you only have one edge. Either way, you can now try to find other edges. For simplicity, consider your plane to be an XY plane and your known edge an X axis. You now need to find the leftmost (rightmost) vertical line such that most of the points are to the left (resp. right) of it. Project all the points to the X axis. You now have a 1-dimensional case of your original problem: there is a lot of random points on some interval, find the interval. Use a clustering method again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super experienced with this, but possibly you could use RANSAC ?
There seem to be many papers on the [plane detection from pointclouds using RANSAC](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ranscac%20plane%20detection%20from%20point%20cloud&aq=f&oq=ranscac%20plane%20detection%20from%20point%20cloud&aqs=chrome.0.57.15922&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Also you might want to have a look at the Point Clouds Library(PCL).It's a pretty impressive project with many useful features including also [planar segmentation](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.php#planar-segmentation)

As soon as the planes are detected, it should be a matter of finding the edges/corners which should be a lot simpler.